# GitLab: how can I tell what acess level I have on a project?

Tags: git, gitlab

I just tried to push to `master` on a GitLab repo and my push was denied with

`remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.`

Looking at [the access level documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html), it seems I'm probably a "Developer".

Is there someplace in the GitLab UI that will tell me my access level and/or full list of permissions on a project?

Comment: @phts: no, I don't own/admin the repo.

Answer (score 11):

You can open your user (in current version click on the avatar on the top-right corner) and go to "Contributed projects" tab, you'd be able to see your roles for the projects you're contributing to, something like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not own the project, you can't (at least, as far as i know) see the list of project members and their respective permissions. But whenever a new member gets invited to any project, GitLab would send that user an email that states the granted permission, like following:

> You have been granted **Developer** access to project

But if you have enough privileges (`Master` or `Owner`), you can see the members and theirs permissions in the `Members` section of panel.

Comment: Thanks, I have such an email! But not having this info available in the UI seems like a missing feature. E.g., I wonder if they will send me a new email every time my permissions change.

Comment: In fact, they *do* send you a new email every time your permissions change

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [List Members endpoint](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-project-team-members) of the GitLab API and check the user `access_level` in the response.

To learn more about permissions (and then you will probably know your `access_level` within a certain project) , check [Permissions Documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md) on GitLab CE project page.

Answer (score 1):

On our current version (Community Edition 15.2.2), there's a menu "Project information" > "Members" which lists all members with their "Max role"

[image: Screenshot Gitlab]

Answer (score 0):

There's nowhere in the Web UI to see this, but it's accessible through the GitLab REST API at the /projects/:id/members endpoint.  Look for yourself in the response, and check your corresponding `access_level`.

As I understand it, 40 is "owner", 30 is "master", and so on.

Comment: Suppose my project is called `my-project`, and my GitLab instance is at `gitlab.my-company.com`. Is there a simple URL I can point my web browser to to make this API call? I tried going to `https://gitlab.my-company.com/projects/my-project/members` in my web browser, but I got a 404. I (probably obviously) don't know anything about "REST API"s :)

Comment: Me neither, but if you go to `https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/36189/members?private_token=XXX`, you get the members for the [fdroidclient](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient) project.  Not sure about self-hosted instances.  On gitlab.com, at least, you'll need to replace XXX with your own token.

There's supposed to be an alternative way to specify the project ID, but I don't know how that works.  So I scraped the numeric ID in that URL from the response from the [starred projects endpoint](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-starred-projects)
after starring fdroidclient.

Answer (score 0):

It depend of the gitlab version in use. I have access on two versions with differents urls :

1. https://gitlab.my-company.com/projects/my-project/team/
2. https://gitlab.my-company.com/projects/my-project/project_members/

to access succesfully it suppose that your are already master and not only developer

Comment: I would like something that also works when your access level is lower than "master".

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the project repository. Then under Project information in the left sidebar, click on members.
There you can see your role on the project.

Comment: This sounds a like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35188394/470844, but with less information. Is it no longer true that whether you can see the list of members depends on your role in the project?